# Photo posted via FB Graph API doesn't appear on the wall (and 2 more FB questions)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I post photo on the wall using Facebook Graph API, just set parameter "picture" and send POST request to "me/photos".

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.imageToFBPost, @"picture",
                               FACEBOOK_ICON_URL, @"icon",
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Usually (basically always) when I add photos to my PF they appear on my wall. But not in this case. I've tested yesterday about 20 times and only 1-2 times photos appeared on my wall. Basically I want them to appears on my friend's feed. **Main question: is there any way to make photo appear on my wall each time she it was posted?**

**Second question is how to customize icon of the post?** E.g. when I of mobile upload under the wall post I see this icon: [image: Facebook Mobile Icon]. I want to see icon of my app instead. I 've set icon of my Facebook app, but it isn't showed anywhere...

**3rd question is how to get link to the Facebook page with a photo?**
As result of request mentioned above I receive "id" of the picture. I want to open Safari with  Facebook page of uploaded picture. Is it possible? I can find only direct link to the .jpg file, but not to the FB page. I've tried to go to `http://graph.facebook.com/photo_id` but it does't work...
Also it isn't very clear for me ho to catch various responses in the same file. E.g. if I do login, photo posting and requesting photo info in the same class. I created `request_id` class variable for that and execute switch/case in method comparing request_id with constants, but this way looks "ugly" for me. Any nice solution? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1rst question**: Facebook decides what to display on your friends feed. displaying one post per photo would be overwhelming so FB chooses to group your images by album into the same post.

**2nd question**: in your application settings page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) you can modify the icon displayed for each one of the posts.

**3rd question**: each `requestWithGraphPath` methods return a `FBRequest` instance ref. Keep it somewhere and once your delegate gets called back, compare the passed `FBRequest` with the ones you kept asside.

Comment: 1st - It doesn't display photos on my wall in 100%. I understand that I can't be 100% time in friend's feed, but I believe logged user wall should display all posted photos;

Comment: 2nd: Icon is set. You can check screenshot (I believe you was talking about that icon): http://cl.ly/131o3Z3k1g3d142N362A Thanks!